# Any side effect of CLLocationManager with NSTimer using such approach?

Tags: iphone, nstimer, cllocationmanager, power-management, memory-consumption

I am working on an iPhone app which needs Location Updates with intervals specified by the user.
Here is the code sample, which I am using to do this:

```
@implementation TestLocation
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    if ([Utils getDataWithKey:TIMER_INTERVAL] == nil) {
        [Utils saveDataWithKey:TIMER_INTERVAL withValue:@"60.0"];
    }
    locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)startLocationManager:(NSTimer *)timer{  
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    // Here is code to handle location updates... 
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // Timer will start getting updated location.
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[Utils getDataWithKey:TIMER_INTERVAL] doubleValue];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(startLocationManager:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

}
// other implementations ...
@end
```

The code is working like a charm.

**The question is:**

I'm using `CLLocationManager` along with `NSTimer`, does this effect **memory** or **battery** consumption? I mean any negative effect on User Experience?

If so, any suggestion, helping links to do such task with optimization will be much appreciated.

**Note:** `Utils` is my class to store or retrieve data.

Comment: out of curiosty .. where are you passing the timer to startLocationManager.. ?

Comment: i mean start location manger takes an nstimer as an argument but you are not sending any argument as the userinfo being passsed is  nil.

Comment: The Timer itself is passed automatically by the iOS framework.

Comment: ok.. is this case with nstimer only or with any type of object.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this will have some side effects, you will not get the desired accuracy. Since it will call the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` every time the GPS signal will 
be come more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a good strategy because you can receive multiple asynchronous location events before the first call to `[manager stopUpdatingLocation]`. That will lead to exponential number of timers getting created.

Instead, just start the repeating timer after creating your location manager and still stop the location manager after each received event.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already took off that Timer logic, because the problem you pointed raised there and I changed my logic. Thanks again..